# Replace CSS by PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm doing a generator of CSS in my website.

With JavaScript, I can produce the CSS code which the user has decided.

By clicking on a button, the new code will replace the old one but my PHP script doesn't work.

To start with, I have just define the old and the new variables at the beggining of the script.

```
<?php 

    $fichier='texte.css';
    $backgroundcolor='background-color:yellow;';
    $background='/background-color:blue;/';

    $text=fopen($fichier,'r+') or die("File missing"); 
    $contenu=file_get_contents($fichier);

    /* Open the file and get an array with one line per element*/
    $lines = file($fichier);
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $lineContent)
    {
        echo ("$lineNumber $lineContent<br/>");

        //Search keyword for each line 
        if (preg_match($background, $lineContent))
        {
            echo("Founded: $lineContent<br/>");
            echo("Previous background : $background <br/> New background : $backgroundcolor");
            //Replace the old string by the new one
            $contenuMod=str_replace($background, $backgroundcolor, $lineContent); // string to replace, new string, file
            echo ("New string: $contenuMod");
            fwrite($text,$contenuMod); 
        }
    }
    fclose($text); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, you should be more specific. The "script doesn't work" is no information at all.

Comment: I have this result : `0 body{
1 background-color:blue;
TrouvÃ© : background-color:blue;
Ancien background : /background-color:blue;/
Nouveau background : background-color:yellow;Chaine nouvelle :background-color:blue; 2 font-size: 18px;
3 font-family: cursive;
4 }
script exécute avec succés`

Comment: Wont it be easier to declare separate css file and switch it depending on single internal variable?

Comment: I recommend to use the LESS,a CSS preprocessor, it'll be more efficient,it has a php compiler available for it,and it's fast and easy.you can use SASS too. http://lesscss.org/, http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` doesn't work with regular expression.

While `preg_match` find the regex `'/background-color:blue;/'` in the file, you should pass to `str_replace` only the string `background-color:blue;` or use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

```
<?php 

    $fichier='texte.css';
    $backgroundcolor='background-color:yellow;';
    $background='/background-color:blue;/';

    $text=fopen($fichier,'r+') or die("File missing"); 
    $contenu=file_get_contents($fichier);
    $lines = file($fichier);
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $lineContent)
    {
        echo ("$lineNumber $lineContent<br/>");
        contenuMod = preg_replace(background , backgroundcolor, $lineContent);
        fwrite($text,$contenuMod); 

    }
    fclose($text); 
    ?>
```

Comment: It will work for this exemple but the variable $background will change according to the wishes of the user in the generator ...

Comment: I just answer the specific problem you posted. If you want some help for a more generic code, please edit your question and show another version of your code.